# How do I get rid of the error 'Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method getCookieManager() not found..'

Tags: jmeter

I have a BeanShell Postprocessor in the setUpThread Group to capture the cookies and Beanshell preprocessor in the main thread (as a first step) to use the cookies captured in the previous setUpThread like:
[image]

I am getting the below error IF I add the 2 lines sampler from JSR223 or Beanshell sampler although CFLAG was declared in the UDV section of the Payment thread:
[image]

ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager; import org.apache. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method getCookieManager() not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler'
2020-06-05 15:37:44,168 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager; import org.apache. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method getCookieManager() not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler'

Comment: This error is appearing for any subsequent samplers which are like JSR223/BSH/.. but it does not stop the script (meaning it is not a show-stopper)

Answer (score 0):

The location of your Beanshell PreProcessor (and PostProcessor) violates [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), the error you're getting is due to:

- According to the scope of the Pre and PostProcessors they are being applied to **all** samplers in the given Thread Group
- One of the Samplers is [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which doesn't have an instance of the HTTP Cookie Manager (only [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler does)

So the solution would be placing the Pre/Post processors **as the children** of the HTTP Request sampler and this error will go away.

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider getting rid of these Beanshell test elements

Comment: Thx, Dmitri. I included FLAG RESET sampler as a BSPost processor in the previous HTTP post  04 LA step and it worked. But it is throwing the same error further down in a BS sampler so  how do I do manipulate/process/write code in between HTTP requests?

Comment: I brought the cookies from the one-off thread group  (setup) to main thread group (payment) by writing a BS preprocessor. Whats the best way to bring it?

Comment: I am trying to do some processing (set the flags and paths for the subsequent IFs) by having JSR223 samplers in between the HTTP POSTs but as it doesn't have an instance of the HTTP Cookie Manager it is still throwing this error so I would like to know how I can I my processing bit without this error? Can someone please give some suggestions?